# Section Text Alignment

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I need to define customize head levels. The numbered section wrapping text indentation should be removed.

The below mentioned pictrue is my required output:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\def\numbered{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}}

\numbered


\makeatletter

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {8.25pt}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {.1ex}%.0001ex
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {.1ex}%11.5pt
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex
                                    {.1ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                              {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex
                                       {.1ex}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[1-5]

\subsection{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[6]

\subsubsection{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[8]

\subparagraph{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```

Please advice the how to get the above mentioned picture **"CORRECT"** output.

Please provide solution how to adjust the section number and section text in between space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just locally disable hanging indentation

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {8.25pt}%
                                   {\let\hangindent\dimen@\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {.1ex}%.0001ex
                                     {\let\hangindent\dimen@\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {.1ex}%11.5pt
                                     {\let\hangindent\dimen@\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex
                                    {.1ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                              {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex
                                       {.1ex}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @carlisle Your solution is good. I have one doubt?. How to adjust the Section Number and Section Text in between space. Kindly advice

Comment: @Vetri that is set to 1em by `\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}` so replace the `\quad` by whatever, but if you are doing much more than this I'd use a package which gives a more sensible interface to changing the layout as in the other answer.

Comment: @Carlisle I got the solution absolutely. I am happy about your solution

Answer (score 2):

The `block` style from `titlesec` does that. To kill indentation of the first paragraph after a section title, use the `\titlespacing*` command (note the star):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\def\numbered{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}}

\numbered

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.333em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex}{8.25pt}%
%
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.333em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex}{.1ex}%
%
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0.333em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex}{1ex}%
%
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0.333em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.5ex}{1ex}%

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0.333em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{3.5ex}{1ex}%
%
\begin{document}

\section{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[1-5]

\subsection{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[6]

\subsubsection{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[8]

\subparagraph{Anatomically and geometrically accurate representations of the
cortex are needed for realistic modeling of SD}

\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: your logic is working perfectly